# How to define default syntax on files without extension on Sublime Text 2?

Tags: shell, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

I've read many posts dealing with this problem, but none has an answer to my question.

As said in the title, I would like to define a default syntax for all files which have no extension. In my case I would like to use the Shell syntax.

I've tried "View/Syntax/Open all with current extension as..." but for all files, I have to make again the manipulation.

I've tried the package "applySyntax" but it not seem to work with this configuration:

```
{
    "name": "ShellScript/Shell-Unix-Generic",
    "rules": [
        {"file_name": "PRE_*$"}
    ]
}
```

All my files start with "PRE_[something]", someone know how to resolve this problem?

Thx!

Comment: The regex you specified for a rule does not match what you want to do. Try `PRE_.*$`. Note the `.`. What you specified maps to `PRE`, `PRE_`, `PRE__`, etc. Basically adding more underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/JeanMertz/925008) with a plugin to set the syntax based on the file name, I've modified it a bit to match files starting with `PRE_`:

```
import sublime_plugin
import os

class DetectFileTypeCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def on_load(self, view):
    filename = view.file_name()
    if not filename: # buffer has never been saved
      return

    name = os.path.basename(filename)
    if name.startswith("PRE_"):
      set_syntax(view, "Shell-Unix-Generic", "ShellScript")


def set_syntax(view, syntax, path=None):
  if path is None:
    path = syntax
  view.settings().set('syntax', 'Packages/'+ path + '/' + syntax + '.tmLanguage')
  print "Switched syntax to: " + syntax
```

You can go to Preferences->Browse Packages, and save it there ending with `.py`, I recommend creating a directory for it (e.g. `DetectFileType/detect_file_type.py`).